# Facebook Custom Payload Button Response In Dialogfow ES Not Matching Any Intent

Tags: dialogflow-es

I've enabled facebook response in dialogflow es, and chosen custom payload.
But when i test it, it matches the fallback intent rather, it was working but for some reason isn't responding anymore.

I would really appreciate an assistance over here.

Below is my custom payload but it doesn't match any intent.

```
{
  "facebook": {
    "attachment": {
      "payload": {
        "text": "Which one do you prefer?",
        "buttons": [
          {
            "payload": "Group Tours",
            "type": "postback",
            "title": "Group Tours"
          },
          {
            "type": "postback",
            "title": "Customized Tours",
            "payload": "Customized Tours"
          }
        ],
        "template_type": "button"
      },
      "type": "template"
    }
  }
}
```